# How to change Subscribe button text to uppercase in mailchimp Signup forms?

Tags: mailchimp

I use mailchimp to send subscribtion mails. In General forms I can customize the design of mails with Design it tab. But, is it possible to redesign Subscribe button text style, e.g to make Subscribe Button text in uppercase?
e.g #2 Change **Subscribe to list** to **SUBSCRIBE TO LIST**
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: IN your embedded code find button value and write it in capslock .

Comment: Is it possible to design it in mailchimp signup forms without making changes in embedded code?

Comment: Yes it's possible you can check my answer how it will be .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found solution for you check screenshots

**Step 1:** http://awesomescreenshot.com/09161gcr88
[image]

**Step 2:** http://awesomescreenshot.com/06661gcvc5
[image]

*Output:* http://awesomescreenshot.com/0c061gcxfb
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Super ingeniously!

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two options that you have to change the text for the mailchimp subscribe button. In the embed code that Mailchimp provide there will be a section like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
```

This is the html for the button.

**Option 1:**
The css rule that will match this element is `#mc_embed_signup .button`. So you can add the following lines to your css file and your button should now be uppercase.

```
#mc_embed_signup .button {
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
}
```

It is important to add `!important` because it is likely that the mailchimp css file will be loaded after your own css file. If this is not the case then you do not need to add `!important`.

**Option 2:**
In the html that they have given you, you can also change the attribute called `value` to other text, in your case `SUBSCRIBE TO LIST`.

```
    <input type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE TO LIST" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
```

Option 1 separates the two concerns of layout and content, so it might be preferable. However for a simple case like this option 2 would also be acceptable.