# Can you make mailchimp use another word than subscribe?

Tags: php, mailchimp

The value = "subscribe" seems to be all Mailchimp wants.  Is there a way to override the value to be ":Sign-up." or some other words with special characters?

This is with an embed code from mail chimp. I was thinking CSS or a covering with it some how with JavaScript but without changing this form element.

```
<!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->

<div class="clear">
  <input id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" name="subscribe" type="submit" value="Subscribe" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know mailchimp but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521094/how-to-change-subscribe-button-text-to-uppercase-in-mailchimp-signup-forms/38522594

Comment: That helped a lot, Thanks!